# Running airflow tasks/dags in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, airflow

I'm using airflow to orchestrate some python scripts. I have a "main" dag from which several subdags are run. My main dag is supposed to run according to the following overview:

[image]

I've managed to get to this structure in my main dag by using the following lines:

```
etl_internal_sub_dag1 >> etl_internal_sub_dag2 >> etl_internal_sub_dag3
etl_internal_sub_dag3 >> etl_adzuna_sub_dag
etl_internal_sub_dag3 >> etl_adwords_sub_dag
etl_internal_sub_dag3 >> etl_facebook_sub_dag
etl_internal_sub_dag3 >> etl_pagespeed_sub_dag

etl_adzuna_sub_dag >> etl_combine_sub_dag
etl_adwords_sub_dag >> etl_combine_sub_dag
etl_facebook_sub_dag >> etl_combine_sub_dag
etl_pagespeed_sub_dag >> etl_combine_sub_dag
```

What I want airflow to do is to first run the `etl_internal_sub_dag1` then the `etl_internal_sub_dag2` and then the `etl_internal_sub_dag3`. When the `etl_internal_sub_dag3` is finished I want `etl_adzuna_sub_dag`, `etl_adwords_sub_dag`, `etl_facebook_sub_dag`, and `etl_pagespeed_sub_dag` to run in parallel. Finally, when these last four scripts are finished, I want the `etl_combine_sub_dag` to run.

However, when I run the main dag, `etl_adzuna_sub_dag`, `etl_adwords_sub_dag`, `etl_facebook_sub_dag`, and `etl_pagespeed_sub_dag`  are run one by one and not in parallel.

**Question:** How do I make sure that the scripts `etl_adzuna_sub_dag`, `etl_adwords_sub_dag`, `etl_facebook_sub_dag`, and `etl_pagespeed_sub_dag` are run in parallel?

**Edit:** My `default_args` and `DAG` look like this:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': start_date,
    'end_date': end_date,
    'email': ['myname@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

DAG_NAME = 'main_dag'

dag = DAG(DAG_NAME, default_args=default_args, catchup = False)
```

Comment: Mr. President, can you edit your post and add what your `DAG(...)` and `default_args` looks like.

Comment: @Mendhak Yes, I edited my question!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You will need to use `LocalExecutor`.

Check your configs (`airflow.cfg`), you might be using `SequentialExectuor` which executes tasks serially.

Airflow uses a Backend database to store metadata. Check your `airflow.cfg` file and look for `executor` keyword. By default, Airflow uses `SequentialExecutor` which would execute task sequentially no matter what. So to allow Airflow to run tasks in Parallel you will need to create a database in Postges or MySQL and configure it in `airflow.cfg` (`sql_alchemy_conn` param) and then change your executor to `LocalExecutor` in `airflow.cfg` and then run `airflow initdb`.

Note that for using `LocalExecutor` you would need to use Postgres or MySQL instead of SQLite as a backend database.

More info: https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/howto/initialize-database.html

> If you want to take a real test drive of Airflow, you should consider setting up a real database backend and switching to the LocalExecutor. As Airflow was built to interact with its metadata using the great SqlAlchemy library, you should be able to use any database backend supported as a SqlAlchemy backend. We recommend using MySQL or Postgres.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean? The subdags are using a mysql database but I'm not sure whether that's what you mean. Can I just change `executor = SequentialExecutor` to `executor = LocalExecuter`?

Comment: Not subdags. Airflow uses a Backend database to store metadata. Check your `airflow.cfg` file and look for `executor` keyword. By default Airflow uses `SequentialExecutor` which would execute task sequentially no matter what. So to allow Airflow to run tasks in Parallel you will need to create a database in Postges or MySQL and configure it in `airflow.cfg` (`sql_alchemy_conn` param) and then change your executor to `LocalExecutor`.

Comment: Allright, I think I understand what you mean! Isn't there a way to do so without creating a new database though? And what's the reason that it isn't possible with the default sqlite setup?

Comment: And one more thing; could you show me where you read that you need to use mysql or postgres in order to use `LocaExecutor`? Because I can't find that anywhere :)

Comment: SQLite only supports 1 connection at a time. It doesn't support more than 1 connection. Hence, you need to use a different database like Postgres or MySQL. https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/howto/initialize-database.html - Check this link where we recommend using it. I am one of the committers to the Airflow project and based on my experience Postgres would be the best option. :)

Answer (score 12):

One simple solution to run tasks in parallel is to put them in [ ] brackets.
For example :
`task_start >> [task_get_users, task_get_posts, task_get_comments, task_get_todos]`

For more information you can read this
[Article from towardsdatascience](https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-airflow-for-data-science-how-to-run-tasks-in-parallel-32f7573068a)

Comment: Thanks for this info!  Now Medium / TowardsDataScience is behind a real pay wall.  So we shouldn't provide links to it any more.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
etl_internal_sub_dag3 >> [etl_adzuna_sub_dag, etl_adwords_sub_dag, etl_facebook_sub_dag, etl_pagespeed_sub_dag]

[etl_adzuna_sub_dag, etl_adwords_sub_dag, etl_facebook_sub_dag, etl_pagespeed_sub_dag] >> etl_combine_sub_dag
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.