# How to execute Google Data Fusion Pipeline from a event based triggers CDAP

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

Is there any way to run a Google Data Fusion pipeline from CDAP event based triggers?

The 1st requirement is, whenever a new file arrives within a GCS bucket. it will trigger the Data Fusion pipeline to run automatically.

The 2nd requirement is pipeline dependency, For example, Pipeline B cannot run if Pipeline A not started or failed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Reviewing your initial use case, I assume that for the **2nd** requirement you might consider to look at CDAP pure components like: *[Schedules](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/develop/en/developer-manual/building-blocks/schedules.html#schedules)*, *[Workflows](https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/5.1.2/en/developer-manual/building-blocks/workflows.html#workflows)* and *[Triggers](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/develop/en/developer-manual/building-blocks/schedules.html#triggers)*.

Generally, designing the run flow for underlying pipelines with some conditional execution schema, you create the *Schedule* object by defining the specific *Workflow* that holds the logical combination of the conditions between pipelines and apply the *Trigger's* model that matches you event occurrence.

According to the CDAP documentation:

> Workflows can be controlled by the [CDAP CLI](https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/5.1.2/en/reference-manual/cli-api.html#cli) and the [Lifecycle
> HTTP RESTful](https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/5.1.2/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/lifecycle.html#http-restful-api-lifecycle) API.

Having above mentioned, it is required to compose an appropriate HTTP request to
CDAP REST API, containing JSON object that stores the details of the schedule to be created, based on the [example](https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/5.1.2/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/lifecycle.html#add-a-schedule) from documentation and for the further reference I've created the workflow , whereas `Pipeline_2` triggers only when `Pipeline_1` succeeds:

```
{
  "name": "Schedule_1",
  "description": "Triggers Pipeline_2 on the succeding execution of Pipeline_1",
  "namespace": "<Pipeline_2-namespace>",
  "application": "Pipeline_2",
  "version": "<application version of the Pipeline_2>",
  "program": {
    "programName": "Workflow_name",
    "programType": "WORKFLOW"
  },
  "trigger": {
        "type": "PROGRAM_STATUS",
        "programId": {
            "namespace": "<Pipeline_1-namespace>",
            "application": "Pipeline_1",
            "version": "<application version of the Pipeline_1>",
            "type": "WORKFLOW",
            "entity": "PROGRAM",
            "program": "Workflow_name"
        },
        "programStatuses":  ["COMPLETED"]
  }
}
```

For the **1st** requirement I'm not sure whether it can be feasible to achieve within the Data Fusion/CDAP native instruments, while I'm not able to see such kind of event, matching the continuous discover of GCS bucket:

> Triggers are fired by events such as creation of a new partition in a
> dataset, or fulfillment of a cron expression of a time trigger, or the
> status of a program.

In such a case I would look at GCP [Cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) and GCP [Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer), nicely written [example](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf), depicts the way how to use Cloud Functions for event-based DAG triggers, assuming that in particular Composer DAG file you can invoke sequential Data Fusion pipeline execution. Check out this Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628152/pipeline-dependencies-in-data-fusion) for more details.