# How to run the same Python script multiple times using Airflow?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to run my Differential Evolution script in Python called **differential_evolution.py**. Each iteration runs for around 40 generations. I want to run 50 iterations **in parallel** using Airflow. I have provided random seed in my script so that each iteration creates different results.

Snippet of **differential_evolution.py**:

**Optimizer()** is a custom class I created to run the algorithm. **solution** stores the solution list in list attribute **x**. And **mape** calculates the mape for the solution list **x**.

```
for iteration in range(50):
    seed = np.random.randint(0, 1000)  
    opt_obj = Optimizer()  
    solution = opt_obj.run_optimizer()  
    mape = opt_obj.calc_performance(solution.x)
```

Each iteration creates two output files: **abc.txt** and **xyz.csv** to store relevant information for different variables.

Snippet of the **dag script**:

start >> create_cluster >> differential_evolution.py >> delete_cluster >> end

This is running fine but taking lots of time when you run for 50 iterations.

---

What I want is to create a dag like this:

**start >> create_cluster >> [iteration 1, iteration 2, ... iteration 50] >> delete_cluster >> end**, where each iteration outputs the same two files abc_**i**.txt and xyz_**i**.csv (**i** is the ith iteration)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
@task
def task1():
    something here

@task
def task2():
    something here

@task
def task_optimizer():
   seed = np.random.randint(0, 1000)  
   opt_obj = Optimizer()  
   solution = opt_obj.run_optimizer()  
   mape = opt_obj.calc_performance(solution.x)


start_task=task1()
end_task=task2()

for iteration in range(50):
    optimize_task = task_optimizer()
    start_task >> optimize_task >> end_task
```

You would need to adjust so the optimizer generates random numbers properly but something along this line should work.

Comment: This code will just run all the 50 iterations sequentially. I was wondering if they can be done in parallel.

Comment: I think you also need to reconfigure airflow. Is sequential or local executor enabled in your configuration file? You also need PostgreSQL instead of the default SQLite configured for this to work. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52741536/running-airflow-tasks-dags-in-parallel