# Airflow Parallel DAG runs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, scheduled-tasks, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have deployed Airflow in Docker with the following containers:

`new-airflow-docker-airflow-scheduler-1 new-airflow-docker-airflow-worker-1 new-airflow-docker-airflow-triggerer-1 new-airflow-docker-airflow-webserver-1 new-airflow-docker-postgres-1 new-airflow-docker-redis-1`

I have one worker.

My Airflow Configs are the following

```
worker_concurrency  16
sync_parallelism    0
parallelism 32
max_active_tasks_per_dag    16
dags_are_paused_at_creation true
max_active_runs_per_dag 16`
```

```
DAG configs are
schedule_interval='@hourly',
start_date=datetime(2021,1,1,0, 0, 0),
catchup=True
```

But When I trigger a DAG. Only 1 task is running. I was expecting to run a lot of tasks because start_date is previous date and catchup is true.

Comment: Which executor do you use?

Comment: I use celery executor

Comment: The catchup option, runs the dag instances in sequences. If you want instances of the same dag to run in parallel, you need to define a parent dag. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52741536/running-airflow-tasks-dags-in-parallel